# (Homework) Converting a function to a CUDA kernel function

Tags: debugging, cuda

I'm working on an assignment that asks to optimise [this](http://www.inf.usi.ch/carzaniga/edu/sysprog15s/facespotter.c) C program using CUDA parallelisation.

This is what I managed to come up with:

```
//...

__global__ void gpu_score_function(void *gpu_frame_pixels, void *gpu_pattern_pixels, void *gpu_results,
                                   int frame_rowstride, int pattern_rowstride,
                                   int pattern_width, int pattern_height,
                                   int frame_width, int frame_height) {
    if ((blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y < frame_height - pattern_height) &&
        (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x < frame_width - pattern_width)) {
        guchar *frame_pixels = (guchar *) gpu_frame_pixels +
                               (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y) * frame_rowstride +
                               (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x) * N_CHANNELS;
        guchar *pattern_pixels = (guchar *) gpu_pattern_pixels;
        int *results = (int *) gpu_results;

        int res = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < pattern_height; ++y) {
            if (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y + y < frame_height - pattern_height) {
                for (int x = 0; x < pattern_width; ++x) {
                    if (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + x < frame_width - pattern_width) {
                        const guchar *frame_pixel = frame_pixels + x * N_CHANNELS;
                        const guchar *pattern_pixel = pattern_pixels + x * N_CHANNELS;
                        for (int c = 0; c < N_CHANNELS; ++c) {
                            res += (frame_pixel[c] - 128) * (pattern_pixel[c] - 128);
                        }
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                frame_pixels += frame_rowstride;
                pattern_pixels += pattern_rowstride;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        results[(blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y) * (frame_width - pattern_width) + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x] = res;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    //...

    /**
     * CUDA
     */
    void *gpu_pattern_pixels;
    void *gpu_frame_pixels;
    void *gpu_results;

    cudaMalloc(&gpu_pattern_pixels, pattern_height * pattern_rowstride * sizeof(guchar));
    cudaMalloc(&gpu_frame_pixels, frame_height * frame_rowstride * sizeof(guchar));
    cudaMalloc(&gpu_results, (frame_width - pattern_width) * (frame_height - pattern_height) * sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(gpu_pattern_pixels, (void *) pattern_pixels, pattern_height * pattern_rowstride * sizeof(guchar),
               cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(gpu_frame_pixels, (void *) frame_pixels, frame_height * frame_rowstride * sizeof(guchar),
               cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //Kernel configuration, where a two-dimensional grid and
    //three-dimensional blocks are configured.
    dim3 dimGrid(ceil((float) (frame_width - pattern_width) / 32), ceil((float) (frame_height - pattern_height) / 32));
    dim3 dimBlock(32, 32);
    gpu_score_function<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(gpu_frame_pixels, gpu_pattern_pixels, gpu_results, frame_rowstride, pattern_rowstride, pattern_width, pattern_height, frame_width, frame_height);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    int *results = (int *) malloc((frame_width - pattern_width) * (frame_height - pattern_height) * sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy((void *) results, gpu_results,
               (frame_width - pattern_width) * (frame_height - pattern_height) * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    int gpu_x_best, gpu_y_best;
    double gpu_best_score;

    for (int *cur = results; cur != results + (frame_width - pattern_width) * (frame_height - pattern_height); cur++) {
        if (cur == results || *cur > gpu_best_score) {
            gpu_best_score = *cur;
            gpu_x_best = (cur - results) % (frame_width - pattern_width);
            gpu_y_best = (cur - results) / (frame_width - pattern_width);
        }
    }

    cudaFree(gpu_pattern_pixels);
    cudaFree(gpu_frame_pixels);
    cudaFree(gpu_results);
    free(results);

    // cudaDeviceReset causes the driver to clean up all state. While
    // not mandatory in normal operation, it is good practice.  It is also
    // needed to ensure correct operation when the application is being
    // profiled. Calling cudaDeviceReset causes all profile data to be
    // flushed before the application exits
    cudaDeviceReset();

    /**
     * END CUDA
     */

    //...

    return 0;
}
```

The program doesn't segfault, cuda-memcheck gives 0 errors and the result matrix is filled.
The problem is, the results are wrong.

I'm quite sure it's some off-by-one pointer error, but I have no idea how to spot it.

I'm working on OSX 10.9, what tools could I use to debug this program?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that this code snippet qualifies as [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It contains a lot of unnecessary things.

Comment: Well, I could delete the first part which is the same as the first program. I'll try to shorten the snippet.

Comment: I don't say that it is enormously big, just the smaller you can make it - the better, and some things here are not directly related to your problem. Also, ideally MCVE should use hardcoded data to simplify the debugging. And it is even possible that you will find the problem yourself while minimizing the code.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I'll have to do it later though, because the deadline is too close. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the bug.

The two if statements inside the for loops of gpu_score_function make no sense. Deleting them solved the problem.

Comment: This question shows as unanswered for the CUDA tag because you have not accepted it. Please consider doing so.

Comment: @talonmies done. I'd like to delete the whole question tbh ahah